# Regex to match a string not starting or ending with a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex. The condition is that it shouldn't start nor end with a forward slash (`/`).

`^[^/].*[^/]$` is the one I have been trying with. This fails if the string has only one character. How should I get this corrected?

Answer (score 2):

Match the first character, then have an optional group that matches 0+ characters, followed by a non-slash character, followed by the end of the string:

```
^[^/](?:.*[^/])?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Mp674r/2

Comment: I didn't think that needed explaining - that regex requires consuming at least two characters, not one

Answer (score 2):

Split the pattern into 2 parts:

1. First Part - not starting with  '/'
2. Optional second part - not ending with '/'.

You can get something like following:

```
^[^/](.*[^/])?$
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a far easier and simpler way to solve this than going with RegEx. So if you are willing, you could simply do:

```
char first = str.charAt(0); 
char last = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
if(first != '/' && last != '/') {
  // str is valid.
}
```

Where `str` is the string to be checked.